# How process csv to hdfs using apache nifi?

Tags: python, hive, bigdata, apache-nifi

Hello guys hope you doing well !
I have some csv files want to put them in hdfs and if a file already exists it should append his content to the existing content I tries a script in python but with no results

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import path
import sys,json
import csv
from csv import writer,reader
data = json.load(sys.stdin)
technologies = ['KPI_2G_NPO','GPRS']
old_path = data["old.path"]
filename = data["filename"]
old_path = old_path.replace("C:\\Users\\12\\Desktop\\APACHE~1\\NIFI-1~1.1\\","")
old_path = old_path.replace("/","")
old_path_list = old_path.split('\\')
def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

df = pd.read_csv(data["new.path"]+data["filename"])
columns = df.columns.values.tolist()

for tech in technologies:
    if (tech in filename and old_path_list[0] in filename):
        if path.exists("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/data/"+tech+"_"+old_path_list[0]+".csv"):
            header_saved = True
            with open(data["new.path"]+data["filename"]) as file2:
                header = next(file2)
                header = next(file2)
                if header_saved:
                    for line in file2:
                        append_list_as_row("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/data/"+tech+"_"+old_path_list[0]+".csv",list(line.split(","))) 

                            
            os.remove(data["new.path"]+data["filename"])                
        else:

    df.to_csv("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/data/"+tech+"_"+old_path_list[0]+".csv")
            os.remove(data["new.path"]+data["filename"])
```

and here's my nifi pipline [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yw9W.png)

Comment: Did you try `PutHDFS` by setting property `Conflict Resolution Strategy` to `append`?

Comment: It keeps getting invalid proccessor